# Calling methods in Interface cause null pointer exception

Tags: android, interface

I would like to call interface that is implemented by class Foo for decoupling reasons but the interface returns null always. Here is an oversimplified example just to show what I am doing. In the real project There is a presenter class that takes Computation Interface in it's constructor and then calls the methods to update the views in my main activity using dagger 2. I can't initialize an Interface in my presenter class or in the main activity kin this example. I know it's doable but I am not sure how.

```
//Interface that has a couple abstract methods
public Interface Computation{
public double add(double somenumber, double anothernumber);
public int multiply(int somenumber, int somenumber);
}

public class Foo implements Computation{
@Override
public double add(double somenumber, double anothernumber){
return somenumber + anothernumber;
};

@Override
public int multiply(int somenumber, int anothernumber){
return somenumber * anothernumber;
};
}

//main class
public class MainClass extends Activity{
private TextView tv;
Computation mComputation;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv = findviewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(mComputation.multiply(4, 9))//here mComputation is null always
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` occurs because `Computation` hasn't been instantiated, therefore, it's still null.

Interfaces, if you're using them as an object like what you're doing here, has to be instantiated because you're treating it as an object.

There's a few solutions for you:

1) You can simply instantiate `Computation` with the `Foo` object you created.

```
public class MainClass extends Activity{
    private TextView tv;
    Computation mComputation = new Foo();
    ...
}
```

This would work because you're instantiating `Computation` with an instance of `Foo` by using it's default constructor.

2) For the methods you have in mind, you can simply use static methods instead. This avoids the need to create an instance of the interface.

```
public interface Computation{
    public static double add(double somenumber, double anothernumber){
        return somenumber + anothernumber;
    }    
    public static int multiply(int somenumber, int anothernumber){
        return somenumber * anothernumber;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findviewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText(Computation.multiply(4, 9))
}
```

You won't need the `Computation mComputation = new Foo();` object with this solution.

3) You can actually just use default interface methods and remove the need to create `Foo`.

```
public interface Computation{
    default double add(double somenumber, double anothernumber){ 
        return somenumber + anothernumber;
    }
    default int multiply(int somenumber, int anothernumber){
        return somenumber * anothernumber;
    }
}
```

Then in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements Computation{
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = findviewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(multiply(4, 9))
    }
}
```

With this solution, you simply need to implement the `Computation` interface, and can simply call the `multiply()` and `add()` methods. If your method is simple enough and the method's functionality is the same for every implementation, using default methods help reduce quite a bit of code.

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer. I will accept it as the solution number 1 works. But you need more clarification to add regarding solution number 2 and number 3. Because I understand you can't have static in interface in Java and also you can't add method body inside an interface in Java.

Comment: The Solution #2 and #3 are actually new features in Java 8 because Java 8 brings about the ability to use `static` and `default` methods in interfaces. Here's a link that talks more about it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods

Comment: Additionally, if you want to use Java 8 features in your Android app, here's the official Android documentation for it: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: In the solution number 3, you aren't allowed to use the same parameter names used in the first default method in the second method.